# Removing Duplicates by Array.from(array.reduce((a, o) => a.set(o.property, o), new Map()).values()),How does it work?

Tags: javascript

I am curious how this code work step by step to remove duplicates?I dont know how .set works and what is the use of new Map()here?,I can use other methods for removing object duplicates but this is probably faster.

```
Array.from(array.reduce((a, o) => a.set(o.property, o), new Map()).values())
```

Comment: A `Map` can't have duplicate keys. So using the array element as the key in a `Map` will remove duplicates.

Comment: This would be even simpler if they used a `Set` instead of `Map`.

Comment: ok thanks,then what is the function of .set?

Comment: That sets a key to a value and isn't to be confused with `Set` which is a totally different data structure. Just `[...new Set(array)]` should work although it's unclear what your use case is.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of the `Map` methods? They should be very clear. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set